# wpf binding event comes after window closing

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, events, mvvm

I have a silly problem that I'm sure many people came across. Nevertheless I was unable to find a satisfactory solution.

Consider simple project (see the code below). When I type text in the field and than click `[x]` to close the window the change of `VeryImportantProperty` comes after window's Closing event. As a result window closes without asking to save the change.

Is there a known workaround or better programming technique? The only suggestions that I found are talking about delaying the closing handler by launching a child synchronized thread (doing nothing) with lower priority. This however does not do much because binding and closing event handlers run in the same thread.

c#:

```
    namespace CloseRequestTestProject {

    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public MyViewModel() { _isDirty = false; _veryImportantProperty = "Change me!"; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        private bool _isDirty;
        private string _veryImportantProperty;
        public string VeryImportantProperty {
            get { return _veryImportantProperty; }
            set {
                if (value != _veryImportantProperty) {
                    Trace.TraceWarning("Binding event!");
                    Trace.TraceWarning("ThreadId is " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
                    _isDirty = true;
                    _veryImportantProperty = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("VeryImportantProperty");
                }
            }
        }

        public void viewIsClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
            Trace.TraceWarning("View is closing");
            Trace.TraceWarning("ThreadId is " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
            if (_isDirty) {
                switch (MessageBox.Show("VeryImportantProperty has changed. Save changes?", "Question", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning)) {
                    case MessageBoxResult.Yes: ; break;
                    case MessageBoxResult.No: ; break;
                    default: e.Cancel = true; break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
            DataContext = vm;
            Closing += vm.viewIsClosing;
        }

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <Window x:Class="CloseRequestTestProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Very Important Property" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding VeryImportantProperty}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" MinWidth="200"/>
        </WrapPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the binding might be a good start!

- that way your VM will be up to date with the UI at all times
- and your `IsDirty` property will be `true` when `ViewIsClosing` gets called

Comment: Yes, this actually works. I wonder if there is other solution. Real life forms often are more complex.

Comment: It works and has a down vote?  +1   If you have a real life form that is more complex then feel free to post it.  This is a correct answer to the stated question.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Threading has nothing to do with this. It appears that clicking [x] button does not trigger LostFocus and textbox LostFocus and binding happens after the window is actually closed or at least has past Closing event on the way to be closed. So, if you don't want to use PropertyChanged UpdateSourceTrigger you may want to force binding event by using UpdateSource method. The following MainWindow member function does the trick:

```
private void TriggerLostFocusBinding() {
        // Gets the element with keyboard focus.
        UIElement elementWithFocus = Keyboard.FocusedElement as UIElement;
        if (elementWithFocus!=null && elementWithFocus is FrameworkElement) {
            FrameworkElement bindingElement = (elementWithFocus as FrameworkElement);
            //update all binding expressions found for this element
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in
                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(bindingElement, new Attribute[] { 
                    new PropertyFilterAttribute(PropertyFilterOptions.SetValues) 
                })) {
                DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(pd);
                if (dpd != null && dpd.DependencyProperty != null) {
                    BindingExpression be = bindingElement.GetBindingExpression(dpd.DependencyProperty);
                    if (be != null) be.UpdateSource();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While the accepted solution is techinally better IMO this solution saved me having to modigy 50+ bindings scattered thoughout a large and complex window.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have UI with dozens of textboxes and you are not happy to change UpdateSourceTrigger for all of them, just add this small hack in your viewIsClosing method.

```
var w = (Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault());
w.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

Comment: This is much concise then messing with PropertyDescriptor. I wonder if there's any catch using this method instead of @user3088037's.